# Error Downloading Java on Raspbian, "20 Redirects Exceeded"

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm very new to Linux based stuff so this may be a simple fix. I'm trying to download Java to a Raspberry Pi which I have connected to using PuTTY. The command I am using is:

```
wget --user=myemail@comcast.net --ask-password --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u241-b07/1f5b5a70bf22433b84d0e960903adac8/jdk-8u241-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar
```

Once I run it, it eventually gives me the error "20 redirections exceeded"
Thanks!

Comment: If it's an option for you, just don't bother with oracle and use OpenJDK: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u242-b08/OpenJDK8U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_8u242b08.tar.gz

- also, you might remove that pastebin link, it contains your auth token.

Comment: also you could try installing with `apt` or something similar if you don't need the archive or just try different mirror of that jdk, which will have less redirects.